# Keep connection between Windows service and Windows Phone app alive

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

So, I would like to have a Windows Phone app "connected" at ALL TIME with a Windows service.
That means that the service would need to know if a device has been turned off or lost network connection within seconds after it happens. On iOS and Android we keep this connection up with sockets. But this doesn't seems to be possible with background tasks on Windows Phone?

Is there somehow we could "ping" the server/service more often then every 30 mins from a scheduled task? The app will only be used by known people so if there is a possibility to "fake" a music app och location app that would do it. The app will probably be released as a enterprise company app so all users will be aware of the possible "battery drain" that could be caused.

If using Push notification, how long can it take before a device gets it and could the service know right away if that device received it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use geolocation service and keep your app in background or even fake audio agent. You are free with choice because company apps have no public certification process.
Here is some info about [Company Hub](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn296515.aspx) and [enterprise deployment](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/2-014) of Windows Phone 8 apps.

Comment: Is it possible to keep an socket connection up using one of these or will it just be possible to "ping" to the service more often? I have no experience of using any of those.

Comment: I think ping only, don't know how to keep connection alive.